# php sql : Is it possible to have inner join with right join

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
table A - columns: A1P A2 A3        Here A1P is primary key

table B - columns: B1 B2F B3        Here B2F is foreign key reference A1P
```

In table B there are multiple field having same B2F value (or A1P foreign key value).

I want to calculate total number of rows of table B with single B2F value matching with table A field A1P.

Actually it will turn into two type JOIN. First Inner Join and then Right Join because in table B it has single A1P value

Comment: INNER JOIN followed by OUTER JOIN is acceptable and frequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,if I understand it correctly, you don't really need two joins. You can use COUNT and GROUP BY

```
SELECT A.A1P, COUNT(*) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.A1P = B.B2F  GROUP BY A.A1P
```

cheers!